# Yellow bell pepper with brown spots inside

Tags: food-safety

I bought an organic yellow bell pepper today. When I cut it open I found small brown spots inside. The outside looks fine. Is it safe to eat? [image]

Comment: Welcome to the site @Rey. It's really hard to tell without a picture in this case, any chance you could add one to your question?

Comment: Thank you. I previously tried to add a pic but wouldn’t upload because it was too big. I’ll resize and see if that works.

Answer (score 3):

Same texture as the rest of the pepper?  ie not raised slimy etc? My guess is sunburn from it's earliest stages of development if from desert or frost if from temperate climes.

At any rate, I have eaten imperfect peppers all my life.

Comment: Yup same texture. Doesn’t appear to be raised or slimy. Thanks for the feedback.